# Use docker api with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, spring-bean, docker-api

Basically, I have a task, I want to create a Docker container when running a Spring Boot application using Docker Java API and then use that container in various controllers. When I create Bean with docker client, I get an error.

Code:

```java
@Configuration
public class DockerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    DockerClient dockerClient() {
        return DockerClientBuilder.getInstance().build();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-02-05T17:42:07.481+03:00 ERROR 18580 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dockerClient' defined in class path resource [it/macgood/docker/DockerConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClient]: Factory method 'dockerClient' threw exception with message: javax/ws/rs/core/Configuration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:485) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:959) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at it.macgood.docker.DockerApplication.main(DockerApplication.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClient]: Factory method 'dockerClient' threw exception with message: javax/ws/rs/core/Configuration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:647) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Configuration
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.JerseyDockerHttpClient$Builder.build(JerseyDockerHttpClient.java:124) ~[docker-java-transport-jersey-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder.build(DockerClientBuilder.java:106) ~[docker-java-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at it.macgood.docker.DockerConfiguration.dockerClient(DockerConfiguration.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at it.macgood.docker.DockerConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$dockerClient$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at it.macgood.docker.DockerConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at it.macgood.docker.DockerConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.dockerClient(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.Configuration
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

After that, I added `javax.ws.rs-api` dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And got another error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-02-05T16:59:23.158+03:00 ERROR 14156 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dockerClient' defined in class path resource [it/macgood/docker/DockerConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClient]: Factory method 'dockerClient' threw exception with message: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/C:/Users/Home/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class to jar:file:/C:/Users/Home/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:485) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:959) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at it.macgood.docker.DockerApplication.main(DockerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClient]: Factory method 'dockerClient' threw exception with message: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/C:/Users/Home/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class to jar:file:/C:/Users/Home/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:647) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/C:/Users/Home/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class to jar:file:/C:/Users/Home/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:97) ~[javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.JerseyDockerCmdExecFactory.init(JerseyDockerCmdExecFactory.java:184) ~[docker-java-transport-jersey-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientImpl.withDockerCmdExecFactory(DockerClientImpl.java:203) ~[docker-java-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder.build(DockerClientBuilder.java:47) ~[docker-java-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at it.macgood.docker.DockerConfiguration.dockerClient(DockerConfiguration.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at it.macgood.docker.DockerConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$dockerClient$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at it.macgood.docker.DockerConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at it.macgood.docker.DockerConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.dockerClient(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

And I don't understand that I need to do to fix it?

What I need to do to create DockerClient, Docker Container and etc.?

Comment: Do not post pictures of text or just link to errors.  The whole point of stack overflow is that your question may be useful to others.  When you do that you prevent it from being searchable and linking to anything other than stack overflow itself is a risk of change or loss.  *If it is text and essential to understand and troubleshoot your problem post it as text*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding DockerHttpClient to the configuration.
Now my Bean looks like the following:

```
@Bean
    DockerClient dockerClient() {
        DefaultDockerClientConfig config = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder()
                .build();

        DockerHttpClient httpClient = new OkDockerHttpClient.Builder()
                .dockerHost(config.getDockerHost())
                .sslConfig(config.getSSLConfig())
                .build();

        DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(config)
                .withDockerHttpClient(httpClient)
                .build();
        return dockerClient;
    }
```

But I'd be happy to know other ways of dealing with this situation